# How to keep the API running in angularjs even on changing the URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a website where the api gets called on a button click and the api takes some time to process (as data is large) making user to wait. I want the api to keep running and complete even when the user goes to some other page or url. Is there any solution for the same ? using angularjs 1.1.1

Currently it just aborts the api when the url is changed.

Answer (score 0):

> button click and the api takes some time to process (as data is large) making user to wait.

You might want to read into caching or redis. Is this data 'fresh' each time? If so it might be a good time to optimize your code.

> I want the api to keep running and complete even when the user goes to some other page or url

Either this is going to become a SPA (single page application) or it will need to become a service worker (ie similar to how notifications work)